# SQL Full Text Search - Disable Dash Segmentation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I currently have full text search implemented. FTS currently segments if there's dashes. I was wondering if there's a way to NOT segment for dashes.

record 1 - `Apples,Pears,Blood-Oranges`

Record 2 - `Oranges`

I want to return all records where the field doesn't contain Oranges. In the example it should only return record 1 but it turns no records.

```
SELECT taglist, * 
FROM contacts 
WHERE NOT Contains (taglist, '"Orange"')
```

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore Dash (-) from Full Text Search (FREETEXTTABLE) search column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532557/ignore-dash-from-full-text-search-freetexttable-search-column-in-sql-serve) AFAIK It's not possible